# Grow window size as you scroll so that the scroll bar is always centered

Tags: javascript, scroll

Im trying to achieve this, even if the user is scrolling really fast, it will still keep up. So say your window is 1000px high. and you scroll down 100px, then another 100 will be added to the bottom of the window, so that the scroll bar isnt sitting at the bottom, but centered in a window that is now 1200px high. And just keeping track of the scroll speed to see how much to add.

So far this is what i got

```
var checkScrollSpeed = (function(settings){
settings = settings || {};

var lastPos, newPos, timer, delta, 
    delay = settings.delay || 50; // in "ms" (higher means lower fidelity )

function clear() {
  lastPos = null;
  delta = 0;
}

clear();

return function(){
  newPos = window.scrollY;
  if ( lastPos != null ){ // && newPos < maxScroll 
    delta = newPos -  lastPos;
  }
  lastPos = newPos;
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(clear, delay);


  return delta;


};  })();

window.onscroll = function(){
var speedometer = document.getElementById('speed');
var current = checkScrollSpeed();
speedometer.innerHTML = current;

    for (i = 0; i <= current; i++) {
    $("#loop").append("<br>");
    } 


 }
```

it kinda works, but not really, adds too many breaks at certain speeds. the loop crashes if it goes to fast

Answer (score 0):

This will take a little work to adjust for your particular situation, but the concept should be good.

Basically, you need to add some margin to a page-level element equal to the current scroll height whenever you scroll.

```
function scrollTest() {
    var s = $("html").scrollTop();
    // add the total height of elements on your page here, if you want to consider that.  like s += 1000 if you have 1000px of page content.
    var newValue = s + "px";
    $("#yourElement").css("margin-bottom", newValue);
}
```

Register it:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollTest)
```